# Liouville's theorem problem

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Hi i need some hints and help with this problem.

Let $f\in\mathcal O(\mathbb C)$
and assume that $\Re f(z)\geq M$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. Use Liouville´s theorem to prove that $f$ is constant function.

I am really stuck on this problem.

Comment: Consider the function $g$ defined by $g(z)=\exp(-f(z))$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming $M>0$, we have that $\Re f(z)\geq M$ implies that $|f|\ge M$. In particular, $f$ is never zero.    Then $1/f$ is entire and bounded and so constant by Liouville.

Comment: @Davide: or you could consider the function $f+c$ for an appropriate real constant $c$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: yes, you're right. Hence we assume $M>0$ without loss of generality.

Comment: More generally, this argument (after an appropriate shift) applies whenever there is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb C$ that $f(z)$ is required to avoid.