# Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be entire and $\exists M \in\mathbb{R}: $Re$(f(z))\geq M$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove $f(z)=$constant

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Liouville's theorem problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68299/liouvilles-theorem-problem)

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be entire and suppose $\exists M \in\mathbb{R}: $Re$(f(z))\geq M$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$. How would you prove the function is constant?

I am approaching it by attempting to show it is bounded then by applying Liouville's Theorem. But have not made any notable results yet, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should consider the function's behavior at $\infty$.

Comment: @lhf You are correct! We should probably close this then.

Comment: @LHS, you as owner can just delete the question, can't you?

Comment: @lhf unfortunately it appears it needs a moderator

Comment: @LHS, I've flagged the question to get a moderator's attention.

Comment: @lhf whoops.. so did I! Well i'm sure it'll get attention..

Comment: @lhf, LHS: In general, it's fine to just leave duplicate questions closed, though I would have been happy to oblige; but now that some answers appeared I think it's preferable to not delete it.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Thanks, I think that was the right decision, it's good for my reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the function $\displaystyle g(z)=e^{-f(z)}$. Note then that $\displaystyle |g(z)|=e^{-\text{Re}(f(z))}\leqslant \frac{1}{e^M}$. Since $g(z)$ is entire we may conclude that it is constant (by Liouville's theorem). Thus, $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Haha.. I just wrote that down then refreshed the page to find your post. Glad to know I was right! Thank you.

Comment: I think "Consider the function $\displaystyle g(z)=e^{-ff(z)}$"  should be replaced by "Consider the function $\displaystyle g(z)=e^{-f(z)}$."

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems like homework (if it is, you should use the homework tag), I will only give a hint.

Think about what the image domain of the function will look like. Can you postcompose $f$ with a simple holomorphic function on this domain (e.g. a Möbius transformation) such that the new function $g$ you obtain is bounded?