# If $f,g$ are entire and $\mathrm{Re}(f(z))\leq\mathrm{Im}(g(z)), \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ then what simple relation can be drawn between $f,g$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am currently studying for an exam, and am stuck on the following practice problem.

If $f,g$ are entire and $\mathrm{Re}(f(z))\leq\mathrm{Im}(g(z)), \forall z\in\mathbb{C}$ then what simple relation can be drawn between $f,g$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about it and can share? Regards

Comment: Yes, what did you try? If you are just completely stuck and want something to play with, I might suggest throwing in exponentials somehow because they can convert real parts into magnitudes, for instance.

Comment: Or, define $h(z) = f(z) + ig(z)$ and consider where in the complex plane the image of $h$ must lie.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76958/let-f-mathbbc-rightarrow-mathbbc-be-entire-and-exists-m-in-mathbbr?rq=1).

Comment: I got that $\mathrm{Im}(g)=-\mathrm{Re}(ig)$. This results in $\mathrm{Re}(f+ig)\leq 0$. I am not sure what else I can deduce from this.

Comment: @anon  Great, now check out that link right above your comment.

Answer (score 2):

As Greg Martin and Evan pointed out in the comments, it helps to introduce $h=f+ig$, which is entire and satisfies $\operatorname{Re}h\le 0$. The function $e^h$ is also entire and is bounded by $1$, hence constant by Liouville' theorem.  Unwrapping this, you conclude that $f+ig$ is a constant with nonpositive real part.

This question is a near duplicate (but not close enough to be closed) of

- [Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be entire and $\exists M \in\mathbb{R}: $Re$(f(z))\geq M$ $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove $f(z)=$constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/76958/)
- [Liouville's theorem problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/68299/)

Comment: Welcome back +1.